# IdentityServer4 Client Credential performance

Tags: identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 with Standard ClientCredential Flow (with no custom code),
normally it takes an average of 30 ms for the request, but sometimes the request goes up to 5 seconds, this causes the average to rise considerably

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You should measure the performance, especially against the database.. Is your client definition in a database? Could also be that the server "unloads" IdentityServer when it is not in use and then it takes some time for it to warm up again